# Verifying that a string contains only uppercase letters and numbers in C#

Tags: c#, string, char

I would use Char.IsLetterOrDigit but I need the letters to be uppercase only.

I can't seem to find a way to combine Char.IsLetterOrDigit and Char.IsUpper because digits won't be allowed when I try this way:

`if (input.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit) && input.All(Char.IsUpper))`

Am I missing something here?

How can I check each letter separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All()` takes a predicate which can be a lambda expression. You can use this to check `IsLetter && IsUpper` separately from `IsDigit`.

```
input.All(c => (Char.IsLetter(c) && Char.IsUpper(c)) || Char.IsDigit(c))
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFYUsW)

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression that matches zero or more uppercase characters or digits:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex r = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9]*$");
r.IsMatch(input);
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FAZl2u)

Regex explanation:

```
^[A-Z0-9]*$
^               Start of string
 [A-Z0-9]       The uppercase letter characters or the digit characters
         *      Zero or more of the previous
          $     End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is suitable for this kind of string assertions.

Working example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  
            
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String input = "THIS0IS0VALID";
        String pattern = "^[A-Z0-9]+$";
        bool isValid = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success;
        if(isValid) {
            Console.WriteLine("logic here...");
        } 
    }
}
```

Pattern breakdown (^[A-Z0-9]+$):

- ^:  asserts position at start of a line
- [A-Z0-9]: the character to be matched has to be either a capital letter or a number
- +: we can allow for one or more characters to be sequenced
- $: asserts position at end of a line